# Dart web app - why do I need an API Key when I have a Client ID OAuth2?

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api, dart

I have a Dart-Polymer [client only] web app and I want users to share data via Google Drive. I want users to be able to "save as" a file onto gdrive and then read/import it on another.

I have set up the credentials from the Google Developer Console.

The app is successfully authorized (with the Client key), but I get **API Developer Key is invalid** when I try to list files on the drive. I have created API keys (payed with several) in the Google Developers Console, although the documentation says I shouldn't need to if I have a OAuth2 Client ID.

Any ideas please?

cheers
steve

Comment: I've been messing around with the googleapis_auth and googleapis packages to interact with Google Drive. Are those the packages you are using? Can you post some code so we can see what you are doing? I take it you are using service account credentials to access a single drive account ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is dart not polymer related. I have faced a similar issue when using the file picker (using dart too). I remember having to enable the 'Google Picker API'.

You need to make sure that for project for which the client key is defined (in https://console.developers.google.com/apis), the proper APIs are enabled (Drive API and eventually Google Picker API if you use it to select a file/folder).

Also make sure you requested the proper scope in your authorization (for example https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Comment: Hi. My starting point was your https://github.com/alextekartik/google-jsapi-picker.dart - *many* thanks.  I've got a bit diverted at the moment. I'll get back to it soon. s

Comment: Indeed, I just tried this example I wrote some time ago and it is still working for me. You need 2 credentials in your project: one OAuth2 client id for Drive and one API Key for file picker  (both with the proper Http referrers). file picker is kind of special API as it requires the API key. My dart sample was based on the following javascript code: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld